# jQuery preventDefault() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

My problem is that there is no way to make preventDefault() work.
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<a class="list-ui-controlcol-link list-ui-controlcol-link-delete" href="http://localhost/lmvc_trunk/pages/delete/17">Törlés</a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".list-ui-controlcol-link-delete").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

Even if I copy-paste the original example from jQuery's own site (http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) it is not working.
Could you explain me why this happening and how to make preventDefault work correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that the click handler is being called?

Comment: Do you mean that the browser still follow the link? Where have you placed your jQuery-script? Try putting it at the bottom of your page, just before your closing `</body>` or wrap it in a DOM-ready callback. My guess is that you try to apply the click-event handler before the element is in the DOM.

Comment: Seems to be working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a9tm6/).

Comment: working fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/4eAMa/1/

Comment: Are your elements dynamically added?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your script is executed after the DOM is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".list-ui-controlcol-link-delete").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

See this page for more details: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Where do you include your script? If you include the script in HEAD when the script loads there's no a.list-ui-controlcol-link-delete is present in the DOM.

Try doing this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="/test" class="list-ui-controlcol-link-delete">Torles</a>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Where app.js contains:

```
$('.list-ui-controlcol-link-delete').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Although I'd recommend using the .on() function as it will dinamically bind the events on newly generated DOM elements:

```
$(document).on('click','.list-ui-controlcol-link-delete',function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```